# AAD, AADConnect, MSAL, and Managed Users Error

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a local AD Forest that is replicated to an AAD Tenant via AADConnect.  All seems OK there, the locals users get replicated up to the Azure AD instance without issue.

I have a Win10 Desktop joined to the local domain, that is running A C# test app using MSAL and calling

```
app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes);
```

This throws the exception

```
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Integrated Windows Auth is not supported for managed users. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa for details.
```

From Microsoft's docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-handling-exceptions?tabs=dotnet) this exception is thrown under these conditions:

> This method relies on a protocol exposed by Active Directory (AD). If
> a user was created in Azure Active Directory without AD backing
> ("managed" user), this method will fail. Users created in AD and
> backed by AAD ("federated" users) can benefit from this
> non-interactive method of authentication. Mitigation: Use interactive
> authentication.

But my user isn't a "managed user", it's a user in AAD backed by a user in AD - just as it says is required.

Why am I getting this error if I'm not using a managed user?

Comment: This is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077335/1330838.

Comment: It is similar, but there are no answers...

Comment: @pseabury As suggested in the above-mentioned answer, please check if your users are recognized as federated or managed.

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity - Yes they are federated