# Federated service returning 403 during Integrated Windows Authentication using MSAL

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am writing a .NET desktop application that makes use of the MSAL library to obtain an access token. I am using the Integrated Windows Authentication method.

```
authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes)
                                           .ExecuteAsync();
```

When the AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth() is called, an MsalClientException is thrown with ErrorCode: **parsing_wstrust_response_failed**.The inner exception is caused by MsalServiceException with error code **federated_service_returned_error**

The federated service returned the response with status code 403.

```
<S:Header>
    <wsa:Action S:mustUnderstand="1" wsu:Id="Action">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RSTR/Issue</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To S:mustUnderstand="1" wsu:Id="To">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2021-11-17T16:56:13.6939892Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2021-11-17T17:01:13.6939892Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"></wsa:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo>
      <psf:pp xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
        <psf:reqstatus>0x8004882c</psf:reqstatus>
        <psf:errorstatus>0x80045b00</psf:errorstatus>
      </psf:pp>
    </wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
  </S:Body>
```

For the same application, the interactive login method works. However, IWA is failing.

Any inputs on what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround could be solve the above issue:

You can run try to run the same code on `.NET framework (4.7.2)`
and try to downgrade `MSAL` to `v. 4.15` the token acquisition .

> For the same application, the interactive login method works. However,
> IWA is failing.

As suggested [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971719/msal-problem-acquiring-token-with-integratedwindowsauth/58077335#58077335) by @Saalim Aslam ,
**For IWA to get it work, we need to have ADFS in our environment.**

For more information please refer the below links:

- GitHub: [[Bug] Issue with MSAL 4.16.0 library when using Integrated Windows Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1988). &
  [Lack of parsing-wstrust-response-failed troubleshoting error](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/54100#issuecomment-627002196)
- SO THREAD : [MSAL error "parsing_wstrust_response_failed" when trying to use AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958043/msal-error-parsing-wstrust-response-failed-when-trying-to-use-acquiretokenbyin)